# My Application should support only 10 inch Tablet

Tags: android

Hi guys,

I am developing an application, 
At present which is supporting all screen-sizes,By my requirement is, It need to support only **10inch** Tablet?

For this i have create **layoutfloder** as below. In normal **layout folder** I have not created any xml.

**res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml**

In AndroidManifest.xml, I have declared as below.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>
```

But in xlargeDevices app is working perfectly.when i have run app in **emulator** with normal size app is crashing. As resource not found exception.

But at last i will be conclude one thing that, My application should run only in Xlargescreens.

Comment: How i can develop an application which should support only 10 inch tablet?

Comment: Well What do you mean by `But in xlargeDevices app is working perfectly.when i have run app in emulator with normal size app is crashing.` I guess it's working in normal size but crashing in xlarge size?

Answer (score 0):

The `<supports-screens>` tag is only for Google Play Store. The Android system simply ignores it. When you release the app, it will be visible only to 10 inch tablets.